# Error in syncing data from google calendar to Jquery Full calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I have a task that, need to sync my websites's full calendar with google calendar private data. I could able to extract data from google, but while trying to display that to the Jquery full calendar, it shows an error that ***TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function***, but when page loads full calender is loading properly. I'm getting this error only when refreshing the calendar after fetching data from google.

Here is the code i'm using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Calendar API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css' />
</head>
<body>
    <button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content"></pre>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var events = [];

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            eventSources: [
            // your event source
            {
                events: events,
                color: 'black',     // an option!
                textColor: 'yellow' // an option!
            }

            // any other event sources...

            ]

        });



        var CLIENT_ID = 'My Id';

        var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];

        var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";

        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
        var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');
        function handleClientLoad() {
            gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
        }

        function initClient() {
            gapi.client.init({
                discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
                clientId: CLIENT_ID,
                scope: SCOPES
            }).then(function () {
                gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

                updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
                signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
            });
        }

        function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
            if (isSignedIn) {
                authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
                signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
                listUpcomingEvents();
            } else {
                authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
                signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        function handleAuthClick(event) {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
        }

        function handleSignoutClick(event) {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
        }

        function appendPre(message) {
            var pre = document.getElementById('content');
            var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
            pre.appendChild(textContent);
        }

        function refreshCalander(eventData) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                eventSources: [
                // your event source
                {
                    events: eventData,
                    color: 'black',     // an option!
                    textColor: 'yellow' // an option!
                }
                // any other event sources..
                ]

            });
        }

        function listUpcomingEvents() {
            gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                'calendarId': 'primary',
                'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
                'showDeleted': false,
                'singleEvents': true,
                'maxResults': 10,
                'orderBy': 'startTime'
            }).then(function (response) {
                var googleEvents = response.result.items;
                if (googleEvents.length > 0) {
                    for (i = 0; i < googleEvents.length; i++) {
                        var event = googleEvents[i];
                        var when = event.start.dateTime;
                        if (!when) {
                            when = event.start.date;
                        }
                        events.push({ "title": event.summary, "start": when });
                    }
                    refreshCalander(events);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
            onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
            onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you know you could do it a lot more simply like this? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/ Or is the idea to let the user sign in and display a calendar from their own account? If so, re-declaring the fullCalendar (as per your refreshCalandar method) isn't the best way to add/remove events. instead use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/removeEventSource/

Comment: yeah i want to get information from their own account, thanks for the suggestion i will update that, but still issue persist their, after fetching data from google, i can't work on fullcalendar, ***.fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source )*** or nothing won't get work.

Comment: you get the same error about fullcalendar is not a function?

Comment: yes, but initially its working and hard coded events are get loading into the calendar, but when i calls the ***refreshCalandar*** method, that shows this error